# How to power off Samsung A6 without screen

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-a5

The screen on my Galaxy A6 is dead. Until I possibly get it repaired, I would like to shutdown the phone, mainly to stop the alarm which I cannot turn off without the screen.

I have seen plenty of instructions on how to force it to reboot (power + vol. down), and on how to hard reset it. But that is not what I want. I just want to turn the phone off.

(it would be easy if I could remove the battery, but that is not possible either, and I didn't think of checking that before buying that thing...)

Comment: Why don't you let the battery drain out completely? That would automatically turn off the device. Afterwards, charge the device when it  is powered off.

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled?

Comment: @DanishShakeel: I'm not certain, but I think I did enable debugging a few months ago to have easier USB access. But that also required confirming on the touch screen if I remember correctly.

Comment: @mivk, you may cross-check that by running adb devices on your machine. If it detects your detects your device then follow my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the battery, as shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVl9EGJdTHE

if you are willing to DIY

(You might need to go that route anyway, if you plan to replace the screen yourself -- which is probably much cheaper and faster than using a repair shop)

P.S. Actually, it's probably best to let the battery drain before opening the phone, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

To shutdown a device with debugging enabled, run:

```
adb shell reboot -p
```